# rails : Redirect after login results in error if a user submitted a form to a POST-only action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redirect, http-post

The use case:

On my website, there is a field to post a comment to an item. The field is visible even if the user is not logged in. The user types in the comment and click submit. Because he's not logged in, we redirect him to the login page. The app stored the location. When he successfully signs in, he's redirected back to the previous location, which is the url to the comment form action, but with the verb GET. I managed to avoid this redirection to the last location in this case and instead redirect the user back to the item. That sucks because the user has to enter his comment again.

For those asking: I want to display this comment field in all case to increase the engagement. Don't want to hide this feature from visitors.

My question is very similar to this one
[Redirect after login results in 404 error if a user submits a form to a POST-only action and their authentication has timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309881/redirect-after-login-results-in-404-error-if-a-user-submits-a-form-to-a-post-onl)

but using Rails 3.1+

THe question is: how to save the post action (with all the parameters) and re-post it once the user successfully logged. Another issue: The post is send via ajax.

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the comment anonymously (using a param in your AJAX request to tell that it's a special case), then once the user's logged in, associate the comment with them as part of the redirect action?

Comment: I'm not confortable with adding data in the db from non authenticated    users